# SQL is_in_stock field not updating to Website

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, sql

I am updating is_in_stock field in cataloginventory_stock_item as follows:

UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item ci SET ci.is_in_stock = CASE WHEN ci.qty = 0 THEN 0 WHEN ci.qty > 0 THEN 1 END WHERE product_id in (1968,1969);

I then Reindex All & Flush Cache: Changes have been applied to cataloginventory_stock_item
& cataloginventory_stock_status
But Products are still showing Out of Stock on website

Note: If I go to Magento Dashboard -> Catalog -> Products
and mark the product Out of Stock and then back to In Stock it works.
(But I don't want to do this for 2,000 products)

Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento version 2.3

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this myself:

status field in table: cataloginventory_stock_item needed to be updated to 1

FYI found the tables that were being updated by using:

select table_schema as database_name,
table_name,
update_time
from information_schema.tables tab
where update_time > (current_timestamp() - interval 30 day)
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
and table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys',
'performance_schema','mysql')
-- and table_schema = 'your database name'
order by update_time desc;